# Git bare vs non bare repositories

Tags: git, repository

It is claimed that if a user created a non-bare repository and checked the status by issuing a `git status` he will see that there are no files to commit; then another user could push a file to the non-bare repository such that the first user who created that repository would issue again a git status command and will find a different object data base, and that is why the bare repository is required in such sharing instances! (this is an example of a bad scenario which bare repository can prevent)

My first question, if someone can kindly provide an answer, is how can the creator of the repository see the changes of the second user merely by issuing `git status` if he still works in local repository; that is, isn't it true that the only way for him to see the difference  – between what he expects and what indeed is in the remote – is by pushing or trying to merge first?  And if indeed he pushes or merges, then wouldn't it be correct to say that this is the essence of git collaboration.  I know that how I think is wrong, but can someone tell me where did I go wrong?

Second question is whether the bare and the non-bare repositories are 2 independent repositories or whether there is connection between the two? In other words, if a user creates a bare repository and then another user clones it (creating a non bare repository) what really happens on the server side when the 2nd user adds and commits files and then pushes them to the remote server – does he (the second user) work with another repository?

Comment: Conceptually, you should probably think of the bare and non-bare repositories simply as old and new versions of the same repository, and then read about what you can do with different versions of a repository in Git.

Answer (score -1):

Once the 2nd user sends new files to the remote repository, the repository becomes non-bare.  The first user will need to pull or rebase from the remote repository to keep his local repository up to date with the remote repository.  If the user doesn't do this, his local repository doesn't "know" about the remote changes and its state would represent an earlier version of the remote repository.

Comment: what you said makes sense, and I do  understand that; however, I am still at the same place regarding this post. I don't understand what does "bare" repository holds -- does it hold the current and past snapshots of the working directory files (i.e., the contents of the files as well as when thery were commited?).

Comment: in principle, yes, a repository will hold all historical commits and file contents unless they are deleted.

Comment: so when I work with a group of developers,we all have non bare repository where we commit our changes and the history is saved, how do we all coordinate the merging between our different versions - -don't we fetch the data each into our local repository, do some merging and then push it with the aim to make a fast forward push (assuming we resolve conflicts on our local rwpository) ?  If so, when we go through  that process do we use the bare repository or the non bare repository ?

Comment: when you do the merging, use the non-bare (latest) repository.

Comment: In that case, with respect to the scenario above whereby various users work on their local repository and then merge the work into the non bare repository, is it correct to say that the non-bare repository is per each user (i.e.  Number od non-bare repos equal to number of developers) ,whereas the bare repository is centralized (used by all)? If so,Who is using the bare repository (is only the creator allowed) and under what circumstances?

Comment: There is one centralized non-bare repository, plus the local repositories each developer has.  Anyone can use the bare repository, though, by indicating that they want to work with the old (bare) version.